# How to close again a dropdown with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I close the dropdown after I open it with a click on it again? If you click it after open it now, it doesnt close. I found some solutions and tried but i could'nt make it work with my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".accordion > a").on("click", function () {
                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                    
                    
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $('.accordion .content').slideUp(200);
                    $(this).siblings('.accordion .content').slideDown(200);
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
.col {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" data-id="231">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="grider clearfix active">
  1.
  </a>
  <div class="content clearfix" style="display:none">
    <div class="grider-2">
      xxxx
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="accordion" data-id="232">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="grider clearfix active">
  2.
  </a>
  <div class="content clearfix" style="display:none">
    <div class="grider-2">
      yyyy
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: toggleClass ???

Comment: You say if it is active, you remove the class active and then you add the class active again???

Comment: I know 0% knowledge of javascript. Can you show me the code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion > a").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $('.accordion .content').slideUp(200);
        } else {
            $(".accordion > a").removeClass("active");
            $('.accordion .content').slideUp(200);

            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).siblings('.accordion .content').slideDown(200);
        }
    });
});
```

Others same

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little confusing because you are using the class active when it is inactive (when the dropdown is closed). Remove the active class so that the accordion starts as inactive.

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" data-id="231">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="grider clearfix">
  1.
  </a>
  <div class="content clearfix" style="display:none">
    <div class="grider-2">
      xxxx
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="accordion" data-id="232">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="grider clearfix">
  2.
  </a>
  <div class="content clearfix" style="display:none">
    <div class="grider-2">
      yyyy
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the js test if the accordion has the class active, if it does remove the class and close the dropdown, if it doesn't, then add the class and open the dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".accordion > a").on("click", function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) 
            {
                $(this).removeClass("active");
                $(this).siblings('.accordion .content').slideUp(200);
            }
            else
            {
               $(this).addClass("active");
                $(this).siblings('.accordion .content').slideDown(200);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have made few changes to slideup and slidedown of the div.**

check the below function which helps to toggle

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".accordion > a").on("click", function (e) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                        $(this).removeClass("active");
                        $(this).next().slideUp(200);
                      }
                      else{
                      $(this).addClass("active");
                      $(this).siblings(this).slideDown(200);
                      }
                });
            });
```

```css
 .col {
      width: 33.3%;
      float: left;
      background: gray;
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="accordion" data-id="231">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="grider clearfix">
      1.
      </a>
      <div class="content clearfix" style="display:none">
        <div class="grider-2">
          xxxx
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="accordion" data-id="232">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="grider clearfix">
      2.
      </a>
      <div class="content clearfix" style="display:none">
        <div class="grider-2">
          yyyy
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```